# Extra url getting appended in image source

Tags: php, html

```
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/B66o0CPxJoqxeKiWDOzMp3n5nsNJ6Tcemt3sHrZ0C5SXqLtZg0hc0z9U8jo=s0-d-e1-ft#http://images/ayay.png">
```

When I am uploading an image this extra part

```
OUTPUT:
```

**https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/B66o0CPxJoqxeKiWDOzMp3n5nsNJ6Tcemt3sHrZ0C5SXqLtZg0hc0z9U8jo=s0-d-e1-ft#**
 is  coming in src part of image.

What it that i am doing wrong?

**SEPARATE PHP FILE**(From here I fetch (imageame)

```
 function sendimg($id,$filename){
        $_SESSION['image_name']=$filename;
    }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="wer">
     <img src="images/<?php echo $_SESSION['image_name'].'.png';?>"
 </div>
```

Comment: GIve us some code, what you got?

Comment: addded it in edited version @rokas

Comment: `$filename` how is it generated?

Comment: i am fetching it from url @rokas